# Ceiling light wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light

I recently replaced a dimmable light fixture with a new one.  When I opened up the box there were  4 black wires and 1 live white wire, 3 white wires and the ground wires.

I had to replace the box and undo the wiring. I've put them back together but now the light turns on when I flip the breaker but it stays on regardless of the switch position and the dimmer doesn't work.

I've done some reading to see what it could be but I can't seem to find why the lights won't comply.  Any help would be great.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?  Also, can you post a photo of the inside of the light switch box for that matter?

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. i've added pics for you

Comment: Can you post photos that clearly show the inside back of all the boxes involved?

Comment: Nice job labeling the wiring in the last pic - that will help. Are all of those in the ceiling wired together exactly as they were before? Also, is that aluminum wiring or has someone tinned all the stripped ends of copper wiring? If it's Al, they had better be Al rated wire nuts! Also, in the pic of the back of the switch, you've left a little bit of bare metal showing outside the tape on the unused wire. That A) probably shouldn't be unused, and B) if it should, all the wire needs to be covered, preferably with a small wire nut, not tape (tape will fall off eventually).